# AUFS only changes permissions of the topmost directory

Tags: permissions, directory, aufs

I have two writeable directories **branch1** and **branch2** tied together with AUFS on Debian 8 to the mount point **union**.

Mount options: `br=branch1=rw:branch2=rw`

**branch1** and **branch2** each contain a subdirectory **dir** with permissions `700`. When I change the permissions with `chmod 755 union/dir`, only the first directory **branch1/dir** is altered, **branch2/dir** ramains as it is.

Problem: Group and other users can't access **union/dir** even after setting `chmod 755` because **branch2/dir** is still `chmod 700`.

Is there a way to make AUFS apply changed permissions to *all* directories in the union or is it always limited to the topmost one?

Comment: What is the unserlying filesystem used? aufs reportedly has problems dealing with btrfs.

Comment: @Ned64 It is ext4.

Comment: There is a mount option **dirperm1** that works around the problem.

Comment: Apparently this behavior is by design: http://sourceforge.net/p/aufs/bugs/21/#1293 and **dirperm1** is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have done everything right, so I would suggest filing a bug against `aufs`.

PS: Kontrollfreak has done that already, and the fix is to use the `dirperm1` mount option, according to http://sourceforge.net/p/aufs/bugs/21/#1293 .  Thanks for your research @Kontrollfreak .

Comment: I compiled a new kernel 3.19.8 with aufs 3.19 to verify this is not a bug in the Debian package and it isn't. So I filed a bug report at aufs.sourceforge.net. Thanks for bringing me on the right track.